# Unable to Enable Neo4j spatial extention

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4j 4.2.3. I installed properly. I enabled spatial extension by using below link.

```
https://mattbanderson.com/setting-up-the-neo4j-spatial-extension/
```

I have added below mention jar in my plugin folder and restarted neo4j.

```
neo4j-spatial-0.28.0-neo4j-4.2.3-server-plugin.jar
```

After that I am trying to execute below curl command but I am not getting any output.

```
curl -u neo4j:password http://localhost:7474/db/data/
curl -u neo4j:password -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"query":"CALL spatial.procedures"}' http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher
```

I am not getting any error after running above commands.

Answer (score 0):

Its Worked for neo4j 3.4.15 version.